# Couchbase Node compiled against different node version

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Getting this error when I run in unix system

```
Error: The module '/app/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:678:18)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at bindings (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:203:36)
at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
```

I tried below solutions and it didn't helped

```
1) 
$ rm -rf node_modules/couchbase
$ npm install

2)
$ rm -rvf node_modules/couchbase
$ npm install

3) 
npm rebuild couchbase --update-binary

4)
npm uninstall couchbase
npm install couchbase

5) 
deleted node_modules folder and ran - npm install
```

while installing or rebuilding i don't get any errors, but during runtime I get these errors.  Please help me with solution to this problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have a very similar issue with `couchbase_impl.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 76.`